# $().live is not a function - JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, popup

In Firefox I suddenly got this message from firebug:

```
$('a.close, #fade').live is not a function
```

Indeed, when I click the image gallery and popup displays. I cannot close out of it. The click event never registers due to this error message.

This is script:

```
        $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel');  
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href');  

        var query= popURL.split('?');
        var dim= query[1].split('&');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1];  

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button

        var div_popup = document.createElement('div');
        div_popup.setAttribute('id',popID);
        div_popup.setAttribute('class','popup_block');
        document.body.appendChild(div_popup);

        $(div_popup).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a> <a href="thumbBg' + $(this).attr('rel').substring($(this).attr('rel').lastIndexOf('p') + 1,$(this).attr('rel').length) + '"></a><p>The Human Diet: By Rene Endara</p>');

        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

        $('#' + popID).css({
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft        
        });

        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');  
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); 
        return false;
    });

    //Close Popups and Fade Layer
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() {  
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
        });
        return false;
    });
```

markup:

```
    <ul class="thumb">
    <li><a href="#?w=500" rel="popup1" class="poplight"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#?w=500" rel="popup2" class="poplight"><img src="images/thumb2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#?w=500" rel="popup3" class="poplight"><img src="images/thumb3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#?w=500" rel="popup4" class="poplight"><img src="images/thumb4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
   </ul>
```

Thanks for response.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Good call @Marko. .live was not introduced until jQuery 1.4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was introduced in **jQuery 1.3**, therefore it won't work with earlier versions.

`.live()` has also since been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 onwards.

The alternatives are `.on()` and `.delegate()`

See related question [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14354040/584192) on how to migrate existing code.

Comment: This simply isn't true, `.live( eventType, handler )` was added in 1.3, see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Maybe he is using a version older than that though...

Comment: Well, somehow I was using 1.2 something. So it definitely wasn't supported. I typically point it directly to the internet, but it's definitely good to know when certain jquery methods are and are not supported because it was driving me crazy.

Comment: @Evan, I meant 1.3...my mistake.

Answer (score 27):

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Since `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7+, you have to use either `.on()` or `.delegate()`.

See related question [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14354040/584192) on how to migrate existing code.

Comment: This is important now that it's completely removed in 1.9

Comment: this is the correct answer for almost everyone who's having this issue  in 2013...

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar `.bind` no lugar de `.live`

Try to use `.bind` instead of `.live`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who is using >= v1.9 please see here about depreciation: [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Find this funcion in wp-includes\js\thickbox\thickbox.js and change the function:

```
function tb_init(domChunk){
  jQuery(domChunk).live('click', tb_click);
}
```

Replacing the "live" method for "on", like this:

```
function tb_init(domChunk){
    jQuery(domChunk).on('click',tb_click);
}
```

If you are using Nivo-Slider, the jquery.nivo.slider.js will need similar changes.