# jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, live, deprecated

I recently updated jQuery from 1.8 to 2.1. I suddenly discovered that the `.live()` stops working.
I get the error `TypeError: $(...).live is not a function`.

Is there any method I can use in place of `.live()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning live() into on() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/turning-live-into-on-in-jquery)

Comment: Related post - [Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).error is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47974868/465053). `.error` is another jQuery function which got deprecated in jQuery v3.x

Answer (score 625, accepted):

### jQuery `.live()` has been removed in version 1.9 onwards

That means if you are upgrading from version 1.8 and earlier, you will notice things breaking if you do not follow the migration guide below. You must not simply replace `.live()` with `.on()`!

---

### Read before you start doing a search and replace:

For *quick/hot fixes* on a live site, **do not** just replace the function `live` with `on`, 
as the **parameters are different**!

```
.live(events, function)
```

should map to:

```
.on(eventType, selector, function)
```

**The (child) selector is very important! If you do not need to use this for any reason, set it to `null`.**

---

### Migration Example 1:

before:

```
$('#mainmenu a').live('click', function)
```

after, you move the child element (`a`) to the `.on()` selector:

```
$('#mainmenu').on('click', 'a', function)
```

---

### Migration Example 2:

before:

```
$('.myButton').live('click', function)
```

after, you move the element `.myButton` to the `.on()` selector, and find the nearest parent element (preferably with an ID):

```
$('#parentElement').on('click', '.myButton', function)
```

**If you do not know what to put as the parent, `document` always works:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.myButton', function)
```

---

**See also:**

- [jQuery - how to use the “on()” method instead of “live()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14703646/584192)
- [jQuery 1.9 Migration Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

Comment: that's great. In most of cases I used the latest approach, therefore replacing code like `jQuery('.upload_image_button').live('click', function)` with code like `jQuery('body').on('click', '.upload_image_button', function)` and it worked like a charm (After cache cleaning of course!)

Comment: +1 I just inherited a very old legacy app with a set of broken click behaviors to fix. The 'migration examples' were spot on and very helpful.

Answer (score 103):

You can avoid refactoring your code by including the following JavaScript code

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    live: function (event, callback) {
       if (this.selector) {
            jQuery(document).on(event, this.selector, callback);
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Should include a `return this;` at the end of the function in order to preserve chaining ability

Comment: Does using this will cause any problems in the future?

Comment: you may want to consider include this inside an if condition targeting a version. eg. if ($.fn.jquery != "x.x.x") { //do this code inside here }. This is required because some old versions may not have 'on' fuction

Comment: It worked perfectly, using JQuery 2.1.4, and running the project in an iFrame. Thanks. Utilizing your code in the example posted here. https://www.cffcs.com/Code/2051

Answer (score 23):

Forward port of `.live()` for jQuery >= 1.9
 Avoids refactoring JS dependencies on `.live()`
 Uses optimized DOM selector context

```
/** 
 * Forward port jQuery.live()
 * Wrapper for newer jQuery.on()
 * Uses optimized selector context 
 * Only add if live() not already existing.
*/
if (typeof jQuery.fn.live == 'undefined' || !(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.live))) {
  jQuery.fn.extend({
      live: function (event, callback) {
         if (this.selector) {
              jQuery(document).on(event, this.selector, callback);
          }
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked super fine for my case: got to work mandatorily on jQuery 1.11.2. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @david this helped me to resolve an issue with WordPress old plugin to get work with the new update.

Answer (score 17):

The jQuery API documentation lists `live()` as deprecated as of version 1.7 and removed as of version 1.9: [link](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

> version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

Furthermore it states:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to .live()

Answer (score 7):

.live() was deprecated and has now been removed from jQuery 1.9
You should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 7):

A very simple fix that doesn't need to change your code, just add jquery migration script, download here
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

It supplies jquery deprecated but needed functions like "live", "browser" etc

Answer (score 6):

.live was removed in 1.9, please see the upgrade guide: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Answer (score 5):

I tend not to use the .on() syntax, if not necessary. For example you can migrate easier like this:

old:

```
$('.myButton').live('click', function);
```

new:

```
$('.myButton').click(function)
```

Here is a list of valid event handlers: https://api.jquery.com/category/forms/

Comment: I think the .on() syntax is required just for dynamically loaded content (for example, elements added after the page is loaded).

Answer (score 5):

When i will getting this error on my site .it will stop some functionality
on my site, after research i find the solution for this problem ,

```
$colorpicker_inputs.live('focus', function(e) {
    jQuery(this).next('.farb-popup').show();
    jQuery(this).parents('li').css( {
        position : 'relative',
        zIndex : '9999'
    })
    jQuery('#tabber').css( {
        overflow : 'visible'
    });
});

$colorpicker_inputs.live('blur', function(e) {
    jQuery(this).next('.farb-popup').hide();
    jQuery(this).parents('li').css( {
        zIndex : '0'
    })
});
```

Should be replace '**live**' to '**on**' check below

```
    $colorpicker_inputs.on('focus', function(e) {
    jQuery(this).next('.farb-popup').show();
    jQuery(this).parents('li').css( {
        position : 'relative',
        zIndex : '9999'
    })
    jQuery('#tabber').css( {
        overflow : 'visible'
    });
});

$colorpicker_inputs.on('blur', function(e) {
    jQuery(this).next('.farb-popup').hide();
    jQuery(this).parents('li').css( {
        zIndex : '0'
    })
});
```

One more basic exmaple below :

```
.live(event, selector, function)
```

Change it to :

```
.on(event, selector, function)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using the Ruby on Rails' jQuery gem `jquery-rails` and for some reason you can't refactor your legacy code, the last version that still supports is `2.1.3` and you can lock it by using the following syntax on your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1', '= 2.1.3'
```

then you can use the following command to update:

```
bundle update jquery-rails
```

I hope that help others facing a similar issue.