# jQuery - how to use the "on()" method instead of "live()"?

Tags: javascript, deprecated, jquery, jquery-on

I used `live()` for generated pages and frames. But in `jQuery 1.9` this function is deprecated and does not work.

I use `on()` instead of `live()` but this method works for one time, and does not work in frames.

My code looks like this:

```
  $("#element").live('click',function(){
    $("#my").html(result);
   });
```

What is the solution?

Comment: [Read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Delegate the event handler higher up the DOM tree.

Comment: The [documentation for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) also has a section specifically about converting from `.live()` to `.on()`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '#element', function(){
    $("#my").html(result);
});
```

The clicked element selector is now passed through the `.on()` function parameters, and the previous selector should be replaced with the closest parent selector preferably with an ID. If you do not know what parent selector to use, `body` works too, but is less efficient.

see [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14354040/584192) on how to migrate existing code.

Comment: thanx... nice answer...