# How to convert .live to .on in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to convert `.live` to `.on` method as `.live` is not used much but I am not able to convert it. Please help me to change it.

```
$(".delete").live('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var b = $(this).parent().parent();
    var dataString = 'id=' + id;
    if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this update?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (e) {
                b.hide();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.delete', function()...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$(".delete").live('click',function()
```

To:

```
$("body").on('click', '.delete', function () {
```

Solution:

```
$("body").on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var b = $(this).parent().parent();
    var dataString = 'id=' + id;
    if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this update?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (e) {
                b.hide();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please also see [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354091/584192) and [jQuery - how to use the “on()” method instead of “live()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703668/584192)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".delete").live('click',function()
```

can be converted to

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete", function()
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#someArbitraryContextNode").on('click',".delete",function(){});
```