# jQuery function works on JSFiddle but doesn't work in my html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jsfiddle

I have a function that adds x px of margin-left to "Karusell" which is a div-box. I also have a function that adds "1" to nextClicked every time we use the first function. When nextClicked is 2, there should not be any margin added when clicked on the first function. This works perfectly fine in JSFiddle, but doesn't work in my HTML document and I don't know why.

```css
body {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    position: relative;
}

#bokse1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#bokse2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#Karusell {
    width: 1040px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: indigo;
    display: absolute;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="bokse1"></div>
    <div id="bokse2"></div>

    <div id="Karusell"></div>

    <script>
        currentNextClicked = 0;

        nextClicked = 0;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#bokse1").click(function () {
                if (nextClicked != 2)
                    $("#Karusell").animate({
                        marginLeft: ["+=100px", "linear"],
                    }, 400, function () {});
            });

            $('#bokse1').live('click', function () {
                if (nextClicked != 2) {
                    currentNextClicked = nextClicked;
                    nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
                    console.log(nextClicked)
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
```

here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbLjcpx1/11/

As we can see in the JSFiddle link, no margin is being added the second time we use the function, and this should also happen in my HTML document.

Comment: any Console error ?

Comment: `.live()` is removed from v1.9 of jQuery, here you use 3.x (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @Krøsh change the live function to on, the live function doesn't exist in newer versions of jquery

Comment: Change the version of jQuery in the fiddle from 1.8.3 to 3.3.1 as in your "not working" example. What happens?

Comment: @Krøsh see my answer bellow

Comment: Thank you guys the problem was the live function. I changed it to on now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
currentNextClicked = 0;

nextClicked = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#bokse1").click(function() {
  if (nextClicked != 2)
$("#Karusell").animate({
  marginLeft: ["+=100px", "linear"],
}, 400, function() {
});
});

  $('#bokse1').on('click', function(){
      if (nextClicked != 2) {
      currentNextClicked = nextClicked;
      nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
      console.log(nextClicked)
  }});

});
```

```css
.nextButtonFalse{display:none;}
.prevButtonFalse{display:none;}

#bokse1 {width:20px;height:20px;background-color:blue;}
#bokse2 {width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red;}
#Karusell{width:30px;height:30px;background-color:indigo;display:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bokse1"></div>
<div id="bokse2"></div>

<div id="Karusell">
```

[jQuery - how to use the “on()” method instead of “live()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14703646/584192)

`.live` is deprecated since jquery 1.9 use `.on` instead for the versions after 1.8

Answer (score 1):

You are using a newer version of jquery where the `live()` function is depreciated, use the `on()` function instead

```
<script>

currentNextClicked = 0;

nextClicked = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#bokse1").click(function() {
  if (nextClicked != 2)
$("#Karusell").animate({
  marginLeft: ["+=100px", "linear"],
}, 400, function() {
});
});

  $('#bokse1').on('click', function(){
      if (nextClicked != 2) {
      currentNextClicked = nextClicked;
      nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
      console.log(nextClicked)
  }});

});

  </script>
```