# Problems Referencing Jquery 1.9.1 but 1.7.1 works fine

Tags: jquery

I am referencing jQuery like below in my code and it works fine:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

However when I reference the newest version (below) it acts as if there is no jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

I'm quiet new to jQuery and I'm not even sure how to test this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Here is a Fiddle to what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/aeNke/

In 1.7.1 the list is sortable however it does not alert the order,
in 1.9.1 the list is not sortable at all.

The only error my am recieving in the error console is "TypeError: jQuery.curCss is not a function

Comment: could you post an example so that we can give a look at the code?

Comment: what is working and what is not...??

Comment: I have updated the post with more details

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you have used depreciated function(s), and your code is now throwing errors.

The *most common error* is through the use of the now depreciated function `.live()`.

For more info, see upgrade guides at

- http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

**Hint:** take a look at all the functions that have the keyword **"removed"**

**E.g.:** `.toggle()`, `.live()`, `.die()` has been removed.

See related thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354091/584192 for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a migrate plugin if you want to use `jQuery 1.9.0+`:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Although i suggest you to go through the `upgrade guide and look for the removed` and try `replacing those with the suggested ones`.

Comment: I have removed the function giving me the error and now it is working with 1.9.1, however I am still having an issue alerting the order of a sortable list like it is in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/aeNke/

Comment: Thanks I have referenced the jQuery UI script in my code now as well, however it is still not alerting the order! I'm at a loss as to why this would be happening?

Comment: have you checked the jQuery UI's version? as mentioned in the updated fiddle.

Comment: Yes I've referenced jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery migrate and jQuery UI 1.9.2 however it is still not alerting the order, the list is sorting fine though!