# jQuery 1.9 migrate live() to on() with multiple events not working

Tags: jquery

I have upgrade jquery to version 1.9.1, but the live() function is broken. I am now migrating live() to on() as descripted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function).

But this senario is not working. May be because it's targeting mutiple events, which are "copy", "paste" and "cut". No error has been captured in Firefox console.

Previous Code:

```
$('#Password').live('copy paste cut', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Please do not copy-paste your password");
});
```

Now:

```
$('body').on('copy paste cut', '#Password', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Please do not copy-paste your password");
});
```

I want a clean and nice solution for this. DO NOT write same code for three times.

Thanks!

Comment: seems to be fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/25TZc/

Comment: @Arun P Johny Oh, I see. My other code may have issue with jquery 1.9. I will check for myself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The big question; if you DO try writing the same code three times, do any of the three handlers work and if so, which?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out finally. It's because I forget to put the code in

```
$(function (){
    ...
})
```

so the event is never get registered. careless mistake :(