# why code is not working with a script named jquery 1 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`jquery.min.js` is working fine, but when I replace `jquery.min.js` with `jquery.1.9.js`, my code is not working.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('#imageFile').live("change", function () {
    $("#imageSize").text("");
    var tt = $(this).val();
    var size = this.files[0].size;
    $("#imageFile").val(Math.ceil(size / 1024));
});
</script>
<input id="imageFile" type="file" />
<input id="imageSize" type="text" />
```

Comment: You don't even have to use `.live` here. Just put the script after the elements and bind the event handler normally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `on()` method:

```
 $(document).on("change", "#imageFile", function(){

  $("#imageSize").text("");
    var tt = $(this).val();
    var size = this.files[0].size;
    $("#imageFile").val(Math.ceil(size / 1024));


 });
```

See the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: If you mean your code should just replace the OP's code, then this wouldn't work. The elements are not available yet when the code is executed.

Comment: I though the elements were already there, anyway I edited and it should work at anytime

Answer (score 4):

Because [**`live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has removed as of `jQuery 1.9`. Use [**`on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead. Please see the linked documentation for more information.

Comment: thanx for your reply, but i have to use jquery.1.9.js, then what change i have to make to work with 1.9?

Comment: @Adeeb: As the answer says, you have to use `.on`. Have a look at the documentation. Maybe this helps as well: [jQuery 1.7 - Turning live() into on()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8021436/218196).

Comment: @Adeeb: Then you might have not done it correctly. Are you sure you read the documentation? The `.live` documentation shows the equivalent code with `.on`. Also have a look at the question I linked to.

Comment: @AdeebKeyaam just making sure, you do actually have the jquery1.9 script in that folder right?

Comment: thank you to all and appreciated your comments and reply...it is working, i am done a terrible mistake, in pressure, i didn't focus that i edit a new page and display the old one...how stupid i am...thanx to everybody again...