# Sum of the value of dynamic elements

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get real time summation of the value of dynamic elements, but I can't get it. 
You can see my [DEMO here](http://gestionale.odoyabooks.com/sum.php).

My code is given below.

My Javascript is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".input_ttotal").each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;

        $(".input_ttotal").each(function() {       
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

Finally, my HTML is:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

<div class="yes">
    <div id="cost1" class="clonedCost" style="display: inline;">
        <table  border="0">
          <tr>          
            <td><label class="total" for="total">Total 1</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <input class="input_ttotal" id="ttotal" type="text" name="ttotal[]" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="addDelButtons_cost"><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value=""> <input type="button" id="btnDel" value=""></div>

     <p>Sum is:<span id="sum">0</span></p>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: your problem exists because jquery cannot detect html that is added in after the page loads. try look up on how to use `delegate`, or the new `on()` function

Comment: Are you consistently adding an input line with an id of "ttotal"? That's invalid markup! Where's the script that adds a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyup is only working for the first element. The new inputs are not having the handler bound to them. Instead of using `.each()` to bind the elements once on page load, use [`.on()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354091/584192) to handle those that are also dynamically attached.

Change

```
$(".input_ttotal").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
});
```

To

```
$("form").on('keyup', '.input_ttotal', function() {
    calculateSum();
});
```

**Click to see it in action:** http://jsfiddle.net/ByLrz/1/

Comment: Yeah it works well. But when i delete one row it does not decrease the summation???

Comment: $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        calculateSum();
});

When i click #btnDel to delete row , then i call calculateSum(); function but does not work. sir i don't know jQuery well. Please don't mind.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. 
$('#btnDel').click(function () {
        calculateSum();
    });

work well in google chrome browser. But does not work properly in firefox. Suppose 10 + 10 + 10 = 30 if i delete 2 row then sum shows 20 . But this will be 10. What's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with newly added elements.  You could use the jQuery `on` method to bind `keyup` event on those elements.  Also you don't need to loop through the elements and bind the `keyup` event on each an every one of them like you've done.  You could do it with one statement without the loop like follows:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.input_ttotal', function() {
    calculateSum();
});
```

Or alternatively on one like as CORRUPT mentioned in the comment below:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.input_ttotal', calculateSum);
```

Comment: Might be shortened to `$(".input_ttotal").on('keyup', calculateSum);`

Comment: @CORRUPT, nice! Yes absolutely.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, thanks for pointing that out.  Yes it's now tested and working :)