# Input Button upload only as checked make it required

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

As you may have seen my other questions almost all are realted to input box and sql's, I'm still learning any help is well appreciated.

The following question is how do I show a button to upload... let say an image... using PHP of curse.. but for this example I will only use html, since the ruslt has to be manage by java...

so I have my button working as follow

```
    <input type="button" id="filers_bordado" value="Upload" class="imgBordado   ">
<script>
 new AjaxUpload("filers_bordado",{action:"upload.php?tmpl=up&amp;op=product&amp;view=product&amp;task=ajaxupload",data :{mname:"filers_bordado"}, name:"filers_bordado",onSubmit : function(file , ext){jQuery("filers_bordado").text("Subiendo" + file);this.disable();}, onComplete :function(file,response){jQuery("&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;").appendTo(jQuery("#ol_rs_bordado")).text(response);var uploadfiles = jQuery("#ol_rs_bordado li").map(function() {return jQuery(this).text();}).get().join(",");jQuery("#rs_bordado_15").val(uploadfiles);this.enable();jQuery("#rs_bordado").val(uploadfiles);}});
 </script>
```

This is almost the same as if I where using [ `<input type="file" name="file" id="file">` ]

the problem here is not the functionality of my button to upload files to the server, the problem is the way that is use... please allow me...

I have a check box as follow

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:changePropertyDropdown(&quot;15&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;8&quot;,&quot;27&quot;,&quot;50&quot;,&quot;50&quot;);" required="0" attribute_name="Posición" class="inputbox" id="property_id_prd_15_0_8" name="property_id_prd_15_0_8[]" value="27">
```

The script in this checkbox is use to add that value to a different value input which is irrelevant for what I need... when the user check that box I want to show the upload button and make it required, to show or hide the button I'm using the same technique as on my previews question: [Show box or input box on checked box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626559/show-box-or-input-box-on-checked-box)

What I can't do is to make that button required... how do I make that button required? ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could add `this.required='true';` before your changePropertyDropdown() function.