# Hide parts of html code base on page elements

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Using a CMS sometime can be a pain in the neck, you work on making some modifications and by the time you finish you get an alert Update is Available... you update your CMS... and ohh noo, all your hard work get's override and you have to start all over again...

The following code is the one that I need to work on:
I need to hide certain parts of this code base on few "parameters"

so here is the code:

```
<section class="grid-block" id="content">
<div id="system-message-container">
</div>
<div class="redshop" id="redshopcomponent"><form onsubmit="return CheckCardNumber(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="adminForm" name="adminForm" method="post" action="/component/redshop/checkout.html"><div id="divOnestepCheckout"><table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<fieldset class="adminform">
<legend>Dirección de Facturación</legend>
<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 550}}" href="/store/account_billto.html?tmpl=component&amp;for=true&amp;return=checkout&amp;Itemid=1" class="modal"> Editar</a> <br>Nombre : Tardoss<br>Apellidos : Notengo<br>Dirección : Lejos del Prado #32<br> Código postal : 51000<br>Ciudad : Mexico<br> País : Mexico<br>Provincia : México (Estado de)<br>Teléfono : 5565478963<br>E-mail : 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var prefix = '&amp;#109;a' + 'i&amp;#108;' + '&amp;#116;o';
var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
var addy80186 = 't&amp;#97;rd&amp;#111;ss' + '&amp;#64;';
addy80186 = addy80186 + 'h&amp;#111;tm&amp;#97;&amp;#105;l' + '&amp;#46;' + 'c&amp;#111;m';
document.write('&lt;a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy80186 + '\'&gt;');
document.write(addy80186);
document.write('&lt;\/a&gt;');
//--&gt;\n </script><a href="mailto:example@hotmail.com">example@hotmail.com</a><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write('&lt;span style=\'display: none;\'&gt;');
//--&gt;
</script><span style="display: none;">Esta dirección de correo electrónico está siendo protegida contra los robots de spam. Necesita tener JavaScript habilitado para poder verlo.
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write('&lt;/');
document.write('span&gt;');
//--&gt;
</script></span><br>
</fieldset>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<fieldset class="adminform">
<legend>Dirección de envío</legend>
<div><input type="radio" value="2" name="users_info_id" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'');">Por defecto (Igual que la de facturación)</div><div><input type="radio" checked="checked" value="3" name="users_info_id" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'');">Tardoss Notengos <a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 570, y: 470}}" href="/store/addshipping/3.html?tmpl=component&amp;for=true&amp;return=checkout&amp;Itemid=1" class="modal">(Editar)</a> <a title="" href="http://www.forium.mx/index.php?option=c&amp;view=apto&amp;return=checkout&amp;tmpl=coent&amp;task=remove&amp;infoid=3&amp;Itemid=1">(Borrar)</a></div><a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 570, y: 470}}" href="/component/redshop/account_shipto/addshipping.html?tmpl=cnt&amp;for=true&amp;return=checkout&amp;Itemid=1&amp;is_company=0" class="modal"> Añadir dirección</a>
</fieldset>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div style="display:none;"><fieldset class="adminform">
<legend><strong>Envase para envío</strong></legend>
<div><input type="radio" value="1" \');'="" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,\" name="shipping_box_id" id="shipping_box_id1" checked=""><label for="shipping_box_id1">Box1</label><br></div>
</fieldset>
</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="divShippingRate"><fieldset>
<legend><strong>Métodos de envío</strong></legend>
<div>
<h3>Envios con Bordado</h3>

<div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'default_shipping');" checked="" value="m8=" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10025_0"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10025_0">De 10 a 15 dias apartir de la autorización</label> ($ 300 )</div>

<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'default_shipping');" value="8cXI " name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10025_1"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10025_1">Envio Express de 3 a 5 dias apartir de la prueba de bordado</label> ($ 500 )</div>

<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'default_shipping');" value="LA==" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10025_2"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10025_2">Recojer en la tienda</label></div>

</div>

<h3>Envios sin Bordado</h3>

<div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'shipper');" value="It4g==" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10040_0"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10040_0">De 5 a 15 Dias</label> ($ 300 )</div>

<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'shipper');" value="JA=" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10040_1"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10040_1">Express de 3 a 5 dias</label> ($ 500 )</div>

</div>

</div>
</fieldset>
</div><div style="display:none" id="divShippingRateTemplateId">354</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="divPaymentMethod"><fieldset class="adminform">
<legend><strong>Método de pago</strong></legend>
<div></div>
<div>
<div><div class="paymentgtwchecked" id="rs_payment_banktransfer"><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'');" checked="" value="rs_payment_banktransfer" id="rs_payment_banktransfer0" name="payment_method_id"><label for="rs_payment_banktransfer0">Forium - Bank Transfer Payment</label></div></div>
<div></div>

<div><div class="" id="rs_payment_paypal"><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'');" value="rs_payment_paypal" id="rs_payment_paypal1" name="payment_method_id"><label for="rs_payment_paypal1">Forium - Paypal Payments</label></div></div>
<div></div>

</div>
</fieldset>
</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div id="divRedshopCart"><h1>Mi carro</h1>
<div class="category_print"></div>
<div class="category_print"></div><div class="category_print"></div><div class="category_print"></div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;" class="tdborder">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nombre de producto</th>
<th></th>
<th>Precio de producto excluido</th>
<th>Cantidad</th>
<th>Precio total excluido precio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!--  -->

<tr class="tdborder">
<td>
<div class="cartproducttitle"><div class="product_name"><a href="/store/15/1/playeras-polo/caballero/playeras-polo-combinadas/p530/P-playera-polo-blanca-cuello-mil-rayas.html?Itemid=1">Playera Polo Blanca Cuello Mil Rayas</a></div></div>
<div class="cartproducttitle">$ 191</div>
<div class="cartattribut"><div class="checkout_attribute_static">Atributo(s):</div><div class="checkout_attribute_title">Posición:</div><div class="checkout_attribute_wrapper"><div class="checkout_attribute_price">B. Frente Derecho</div></div><div class="checkout_attribute_wrapper"><div class="checkout_attribute_price">C. Manga Derecha</div></div><div class="checkout_attribute_wrapper"><div class="checkout_attribute_price">F. Espalda Alta</div></div></div>
<div class="cartaccessory"></div>
<div class="cartwrapper"></div>
<div class="cartuserfields"></div>
</td>
<td><div class="product_image">IMAGE.JPG</div></td>
<td>$ 191</td>
<td><label>70</label></td>
<td>$ 13,370</td>
</tr>
<!--  -->

<tr class="tdborder">
<td>
<div class="cartproducttitle"><div class="product_name"><a href="/component/redshop/88/1/tallas/tm-p530-1/P-m.html?Itemid=1">M</a></div></div>
<div class="cartproducttitle">$ 0</div>
<div class="cartattribut"></div>
<div class="cartaccessory"></div>
<div class="cartwrapper"></div>
<div class="cartuserfields"></div>
</td>
<td><div class="product_image">NOIMAGE.JPG</div></td>
<td>$ 0</td>
<td><label>25</label></td>
<td>$ 0</td>
</tr>
<!--  -->

<tr class="tdborder">
<td>
<div class="cartproducttitle"><div class="product_name"><a href="/component/redshop/89/1/tallas/tg-p530-1/P-g.html?Itemid=1">G</a></div></div>
<div class="cartproducttitle">$ 0</div>
<div class="cartattribut"></div>
<div class="cartaccessory"></div>
<div class="cartwrapper"></div>
<div class="cartuserfields"></div>
</td>
<td><div class="product_image">NOIMAGE.JPG</div></td>
<td>$ 0</td>
<td><label>32</label></td>
<td>$ 0</td>
</tr>
<!--  -->
</tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="50%" valign="top">
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="cart_customer_note">Observaciones del cliente<br><textarea id="customer_note" name="customer_note"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="cart_requisition_number">Su referencia de pedido<br><input value="" id="requisition_number" name="requisition_number">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br></td>
<td width="50%" valign="top" align="right"><br><br>
<table width="100%" border="0" class="cart_calculations">
<tbody>
<tr class="tdborder">
<td><b>Producto sin IVA Subtotal</b></td>
<td width="100">$ 13,370</td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<tr>
<td><b>Envío con IVA</b></td>
<td width="100"><span id="spnShippingrate">$ 300</span></td>
</tr>
<!--  -->
<!-- -->
<tr>
<td>
<div class="singleline"><strong>Total:</strong></div>
</td>
<td width="100">
<div class="singleline"><span id="spnTotal">$ 13,670</span></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>Recibir ofertas y otros boletines de noticias. <input type="checkbox" ''="" value="1" name="newsletter_signup"></div>
<div></div>
<div><div style="float: right;" id="checkoutfinal"><input type="button" onclick="if(chkvalidaion()){checkout_disable('checkout_final');}" value="Pedido: Paso final" class="greenbutton" name="checkout_final" id="checkout_final"><input type="hidden" value="checkoutfinal" name="task"><input type="hidden" value="checkout" name="view"><input type="hidden" value="com_redshop" name="option"><input type="hidden" value="1" id="onestepItemid" name="Itemid"><input type="hidden" value="3" name="users_info_id"><input type="hidden" value="" name="order_id"></div><input type="button" onclick="javascript:document.location='/component/redshop/1/?Itemid=1'" value="Continar" class="blackbutton"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></div><div style="display:none" id="divRedshopCartTemplateId">360</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><div id="responceonestep" style="display:none"></div></form><script type="text/javascript">
function chkvalidaion() {
if (document.getElementById('termscondition')) {
var termscondition = document.getElementById('termscondition').checked;

if (!termscondition) {
alert("Por favor, seleccione los términos y condiciones como correctos.");
return false;
}
}
return true;
}
function checkout_disable(val) {
document.adminForm.submit();
document.getElementById(val).disabled = true;
var op = document.getElementById(val);
op.setAttribute("style", "opacity:0.3;");

if (op.style.setAttribute) //For IE
op.style.setAttribute("filter", "alpha(opacity=30);");

}
</script></div></section>
```

This code display 2 "groups" but only 1 need to be show:

```
Envios con Bordado
De 10 a 15 dias apartir de la autorización ($ 300 )
Envio Express de 3 a 5 dias apartir de la prueba de bordado ($ 500 )
Recojer en la tienda

Envios sin Bordado
De 5 a 15 Dias ($ 300 )
Express de 3 a 5 dias ($ 500 )
```

now, the code that I can work with to make this work is the following:

```
<div class="cartattribut">

<div class="checkout_attribute_wrapper">
   <div class="checkout_attribute_price">B. Frente Derecho</div>
</div>

<div class="checkout_attribute_wrapper">
   <div class="checkout_attribute_price">C. Manga Derecha</div>
</div>

<div class="checkout_attribute_wrapper">
   <div class="checkout_attribute_price">F. Espalda Alta</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="cartaccessory"></div>
<div class="cartwrapper"></div>
<div class="cartuserfields"></div>
```

if class="checkout_attribute_price" exist in the page 
then hide

```
Envios sin Bordado
[]De 5 a 15 Dias ($ 300 )
[]Express de 3 a 5 dias ($ 500 )
```

if class="checkout_attribute_price" is not present on page
then hide

```
Envios con Bordado
[]De 10 a 15 dias apartir de la autorización ($ 300 )
[]Envio Express de 3 a 5 dias apartir de la prueba de bordado ($ 500 )
[]Recojer en la tienda
```

The code for both blocks is:

```
<div id="divShippingRate"><fieldset>
<legend><strong>Métodos de envío</strong></legend>
<div>
<h3>Envios con Bordado</h3>

<div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'default_shipping');" checked="" value="Cs" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10025_0"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10025_0">De 10 a 15 dias apartir de la autorización</label> ($ 300 )</div>

<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'default_shipping');" value="ss" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10025_1"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10025_1">Envio Express de 3 a 5 dias apartir de la prueba de bordado</label> ($ 500 )</div>

<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'default_shipping');" value="dd" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10025_2"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10025_2">Recojer en la tienda</label></div>

</div>

<h3>Envios sin Bordado</h3>
<div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'shipper');" value="ff" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10040_0"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10040_0">De 5 a 15 Dias</label> ($ 300 )</div>
<div><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onestepCheckoutProcess(this.name,'shipper');" value="gg" name="shipping_rate_id" id="shipping_rate_id_10040_1"><label for="shipping_rate_id_10040_1">Express de 3 a 5 dias</label> ($ 500 )</div>
</div>

</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I have done this using PHP and changing the source code for this CMS about 3 months ago, but then an update had to be done and I lost all my changes... then I did it all over again.. and again another update... so this time I wanna do it without changing the source code for the cms...

As I have said before I know very, veerrryyy little about java, any help will be great appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: never ever modify core code ofa framework/cms just like that. U should extend classes and override methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should never hack CMS or in fact any open source code. You should either contribute them or override them.

1. In terms of redSHOP, you can use it's template system to override view and template files. You may follow this guide http://wiki.redcomponent.com/index.php?title=redSHOP:Working_with_redSHOP_Templates
2. redSHOP also has plugin architecture to change the core behaviour without breaking upgrades. Here is a guide for it http://wiki.redcomponent.com/index.php?title=redSHOP:Product_Plugin
3. You can override Joomla! MVC using following guide https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core. Please use https://github.com/redCOMPONENT-COM/mvcOverride version of MVC override, as it has improvements in original plugin and also support joomla 3.x
4. This guide will help you to learn how output overrides work in joomla

   - https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides
   - https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core
   - https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla