# JQuery and live()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add more fields to a dynamically generated form. 
User clicks 'add multiple choice' button, a multiple choice form is generated.
Then they should be able to add more 'wrong answer' fields to this form when clicked, but it's not working. I know jquery's `.live()` is the right way to do it, but I can't get it to work.

```
$('button.btn-wrong').live('click', function(e) {
    alert("yay!");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SWCE4/

**Working jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/SWCE4/4/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function

Comment: I also sometimes wonder why `$("button.btn-wrong").goToAPI()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/live/

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

```
$(document).on("click", "button.btn-wrong", function(event) {
    alert("yay!");
});
```

Comment: @karthikr Thems the breaks.

Answer (score 2):

[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated in jQuery `1.7` and removed in version `1.9` . You need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn-wrong', function(e) {
    alert("yay!");
})
```

Comment: Updated, but still not working. http://jsfiddle.net/SWCE4/3/

Comment: can you fix the fiddle ?

Comment: Did you test it out? Click on "create" and you will see

Answer (score 0):

`$.live` was [deprecated on jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use `$.on` , for sample:

```
$('button.btn-wrong').on('click', function(e) {
    alert("yay!");
});
```