# Ajax onchange is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange

I have an Ajax function which checks whether `username` is available or not. But if I use a button and click function it works. I don't want to use button. So I am checking availability on changing the `username2` field. But is is not working. No Ajax call is going.

```
$('#user_name2').change(function(){

    //$(".help-block1").hide();
    var user_name = $("#user_name2").val();
    var name = $("#u_name").val();
    //var hidd = $("#hidd").val();
    var baseurl = $("#site_url").val();

    if (user_name == '') {
        $("#user_name2").after('<p class="help-block1"><b style="color:red;">Enter a username first</b></p>');
    }
    else if (user_name == name) {
        $("#user_name2").after('<p class="help-block1"><b style="color:red;">This is current username</b></p>');
    }
    else {

        $.ajax({
            url: "" + baseurl + "user/check_user",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                    user_name: user_name
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.res_user == 'exist') {

                    $("#user_name2").after('<p class="help-block1"><b style="color:red;">Username alredy exist</b></p>');
                    $("#user_name2").focus();
                    $("#hidd").val('fail');
                }
                else if (response.res_user == 'available') {
                   $("#user_name2").after('<p class="help-block1"><b style="color:' + response.status + ';">Username available</b></p>');
                }
                else {
                    $("#user_name2").after('<p class="help-block1"><b style="color:red;">Error. Try again</b></p>');
                }
            }
        });
        //return false;
    }
});
```

And HTML part is here

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="form-control" id="user_name2" placeholder="" value="' . $res[0]->u_name . '"required>
    <input type="hidden" id="u_name" value="' . $res[0]->u_name . '">
</div>
```

Comment: @MohammadAdil Adil : Sorry... Now see question is edited

Comment: Binding change eventlistener on textfield you need to lose focus from input text element to send ajax request?

Comment: What you mean? I couldn't understand.

Comment: Are you clicking outside the textfield? Because if not your ajax will not fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understading, you bind your event on `click`. i think you should bind your event on `change`.

may be possible, it will help you.

please use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#username2').live('change', function() {});
});
/* put select box id at the place of username2 */
```

[image]

Comment: please have a look on attached image, i think it will produce error. you have to replace "username2" with your element id, on which you have to bind your event.

Comment: That I know. It doesn't show a simple error. It is syntax error

Comment: Thak you dude. It was not that problem. I didn't make any changes in text field. That's why $(document).ready(function() did not work.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() should be $(document).ready(function() {}); and please check your jquery version because some new jquery does not support to `live`. If your jquery version is greater than or equal 1.7, then you can use `on`. `On` method is replacement of `live`. for info about `on` visit [click here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

use .on instead of .live

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#user_name2').on('change', function() {

    });
});
```

[jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/19/

NOTE: I tested that ur siteurl comes undefined so have a look at the code the part you havnt posted in ur question

Comment: Still no.. Updated my question with HTML. Please check

Comment: @SpamBox Whats not working? See your web console and let us know what errors are being logging.

Comment: I have attached demo plz go through its going till ajax call so I guess some problem in ur ajax call or in server side coz till now its working as u wanted @SpamBox

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user_check').change(function() {
        // your code here
    });
});
```

use `$('#user_check')` or `$('#user_name2')` depending on the `id` you set in the `HTML` since you edited your question.

**Also**

I think your `HTML` is invalid.

you should fix

```
value="' . $res[0]->u_name . '"
```

with

```
value="<?php echo $res[0]->u_name; ?>"
```

in both your `<input>`

Comment: It was mistake in question. Updated qeustion with actual code. It is not working

Comment: @SpamBox yeah I just saw it. Btw, try now, with the `$(document).ready` as well

Comment: Still no.. Updated my question with HTML. Please check

Comment: No problem with html. It is inside the php echo.