# Jquery Live Selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code like this,

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="post-activity">
        <i class="loading-icon"></i>
        <button onclick="ChangeColor(this);">Change Color</button>
    </div>
//Will be code
</div>
```

When my project working, and I click the trigger element, I code changed statu like this,

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="post-activity">
        <i class="loading-icon"></i>
        <button onclick="ChangeColor(this);">Change Color</button>
    </div>
    <div class="comments-ch"></div>
</div>
```

And my function is,

```
function ChangeColor(element)
{
    $(element).closest(".panel-footer").find(".comments-ch").css("background-color","#CC0000");
}
```

not working. Because, `<div class="comments-ch"></div>` is a live/append/new code.

But If I run this code, it's working

```
function ChangeColor(element)
 {
     $(element).closest(".panel-footer").find(".post-activity").css("background-color","#CC0000")
 }
```

bacause `<div class="post-activity">...</div>` code existing before run the application.

How can i reach the append/live code (.comments-ch)? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)

Comment: live has been depreciated, update that first and then look into delegated events

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the CSS of an element before it exists? That's impossible. If not, `ChangeColor` will work as long as the element exists *at the moment* the event handler is *called*.

Comment: Does `<div class="comments-ch"></div>` exist when the button is clicked? I'm confused.

Comment: `<div class="comments-ch"></div>` not exist. When visible/append the button is clicked. But the ChangeColor method is exist.

Comment: You'd have to manually record which operations you performed and then replay them once the element exists. You might want to have a look at React with which something like this would be easier (the color would be part of the state of the component), but it might be a bigger step for you to learn about this now, don't know. https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery `click` handler instead of `onclick` attribute like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/43bbrtuL/)? First click add, then change - the div style changes. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I would also suggest you reading this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick) on jQuery click vs onclick.

Answer (score 0):

The live syntax is generally as follows

```
$(".selector-class").live('event', function () {
     //do your logic here
}
```

The event part may be click (element clicks), keyup, keydown etc

Cheers

Comment: And how does this related to / solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to get rid of `onclick` event handler in your markup, at least this will keep your markup separate from javascript (see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick) for more information). So your change button should look something like this:

```
<button id="btnChange">Change Color</button>
```

And in javascript code (which should be executed on DOM ready):

```
$("#btnChange").click(function() {
    ChangeColor(this);
});
function ChangeColor(element)
{
    $(element).closest(".panel-footer").find(".comments-ch").css("background-color","#CC0000");
}
```

You can combine 2 functions in one, I kept it just to make the least changes in your code it's possible. Here is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/43bbrtuL/1/).

Comment: Perfectly. "How can i reach the append/live code (.comments-ch)?" - the demo shows how to do this and works as expected.

Comment: From the comments it seems like the OP is changing the CSS *before* the new element was added and he somehow wants retroactively apply the CSS change once the element was added. I think that's what the statements means. He already seems to know how to append new elements and how to select existing elements. But of course I could also be wrong.

Comment: Well, as I understood it, he just can't change the color of the element because by the time the function is created, there element does not yet exist and even after dynamically adding element to DOM the function doesn't work (I've reproduced this behaviour before giving the answer). But until OP will clarify what exactly did he mean we can only guess...