# Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined even I have added CDN ref

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cdn

When I add this code part to my ASP.net project I got error says "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined".
Since I'm using CDN for js files hope I dont need to js reference files to my project.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnCity").live("click", function () {
            var city = {};
            city.Name = "Mumbai";
            city.Population = 2000;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'CS.aspx/GetCity',
                data: "{city:" + JSON.stringify(city) + "}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d.Name);
                    alert(r.d.Population);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you see any error (404 ) in console of browser ?

Comment: Before moving to browser I got windows popup shows this error in Visual Studio.

Comment: try changing `live` to `on` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function