# transitioning from .live to .on in updated jQuery Library

Tags: jquery

following this link:

[jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)

I feel like what I have is right, but it's not executing. I'm upgrading from jQuery `1.5` to `1.9`, I've replaced `.live()` with `.on()` but my code still isn't executing properly. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

was:

```
$('a[rel != "noAJAX"]').live('click', function(event){
```

Now:

```
   $('a[rel != "noAJAX"]').on('click', 'a', function){
```

Full code:

```
$(function(){ 
  // Link handling.
  $('a[rel != "noAJAX"]').on('click', 'a', function){   
    if ($(this).attr('name') != ""){        
        var currentDiv = $(this).attr('name');      
    }else{      
        var currentDiv = divID;         
    }   
    $(currentDiv).html(loadingHTML);        
    $(currentDiv).load($(this).attr('href'));   
    event.preventDefault();     
  }); 
  $('form[rel != "noAJAX"]').on('submit', function(event){  
    if ($(this).attr('name') != ""){                
        var currentDiv = $(this).attr('name');      
    }else{      
        var currentDiv = divID;         
    }   
    $(currentDiv).html(loadingHTML);    
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(html){         
        $(currentDiv).html(html);       
    });
    return false;   
  });  
});
```

Comment: Did you do what I suggested in the comments on your last question?

Comment: @MelanciaUK That is not "live" though.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `.on()` is incorrect, and you prematurely closed the function:

```
 $('a[rel != "noAJAX"]').on('click', 'a', function){ ... }
```

Even if you correct your syntax into the following, it will not work:

```
$('a[rel != "noAJAX"]').on('click', 'a', function(){ ... });
```

The above line simply instructs jQuery to listen for the click event bubbling up to the anchor element with the `rel` attribute of "noAJAX", and the event has to originate from a nested anchor element. In addition, the attribute selector `!=` is invalid. You might want to try looking at `:not()` instead. You should try:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([rel="noAJAX"])', function() {...});
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/rh38eu4n/