# Camera slideshow plugin not working

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have been having issues with using this open source plugin in one of my projects, http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera

It is a slideshow plugin, and I'm trying to implement it in a basic method.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div align="center">        
        <div class="camera_wrap camera_charcoal_skin" id="slideshow">
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_1.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_2.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_3.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_4.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_5.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_6.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_7.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_8.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_9.jpg"></div>
            <div data-src="/resources/img/slideshow/image_10.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#slideshow").camera({
                height: '30%',
                thumbnails: 'false',
                overlayer: 'true',
                loader: 'bar',
                time: '1000',
                navigationHover: true
            });
        });
```

The slideshow works halfway. The forst image in the slideshow is displayed. The loading bar works fine as desired. However, when it proceeds to the second image, it just stops working. Neither can I navigate through the images, nor does it automatically open the next image. It just freezes.

Also, no transition effect is being shown. I'm unable to find where I went wrong.. Please review my code..

Comment: check for any `console errors`

Comment: jquery.easing.1.3.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery-2.2.3.js:6381 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
jquery-2.2.3.js:6381 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a functionTween.run @ jquery-2.2.3.js:6381Animation.tick @ jquery-2.2.3.js:6717jQuery.fx.tick @ jquery-2.2.3.js:7037

Comment: According to the console the problem lies in the jQuery or the jQuery easing library I got from the camera plugin.. Maybe I can try changing the libs with a different version?

Comment: Try having the compatible versions.. and yes this is purely `jquery` library issue..

Comment: The problem's sorted! The jQuery.easing.1.3 library I was using was invalid.. Probably I made an error while downloading it.. Replaced the jQuery Easing library, and everything works fine now!! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

This because jQuery `.live()` has been removed in version 1.9 onwards. If you seach on camera js file you will find this .live function.

You must not simply replace `.live()` with `.on()`

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function) for more details.