# Couldn't hit the javascript files in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I can't able to hit the javascript when I click on the button. 
Previously the application is in Rails 3.2 and now I migrated to 4.2.6. I didn't change any js related ones. Please help.
This is my code in short:

app/views/reports/_creation.html.erb:

```
<div id="instagram-inline-js">
  <%= render :partial => "photos_inline_js" %>
</div>
<a class="purple_button _round_5" id="select-files-upload-button">Select file(s)</a>
```

app/views/reports/_photos_inline_js.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#select-files-upload-button').live("click", function() {
      $('#select-photos').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed in jQuery version 1.9., so use `.on()` - `$('#select-files-upload-button').on("click", function() {...})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this .....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#select-files-upload-button').on("click", function() {
      $('#select-photos').show();
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will work for you.

live is deprecated .....

Please refer this answer [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can tried this code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#select-files-upload-button", function() {
  $('#select-photos').show();
});
```