# JQuery migrate not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

I am using `JQuery 1.6.1` and I want to upgrade it to `JQuery 3.0.0` and I did it with `jquery-migrate-3.0.0` but got an error `TypeError: $(...).live is not a function` and why JQuery migrate is working?

This is the JQuery load:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>
```

Inspect element screenshot:

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards .you need to use .on() function

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function

Comment: I know @Dinesh but what is the migrating rule in this case?

Comment: @Dinesh Isn't that the purpose of the jquery-migrate library, to provide compatibility with functions that have been removed?

Comment: can you please refer this link https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#note-if-you-have-not-yet-upgraded-to-112x-or-22x-first-upgrade-to-them-and-use-jquery-migrate-1x-to-resolve-any-compatibility-issues-before-using-jquery-migrate-30-and-upgrading-to-jquery-30