# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).error is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jquery examples - 4</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
</head>
<body>

<input id="name" type="text" name="">
<input id="button" type="button" value="load" name="">
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectors12.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
$('#button').click(function() { 
var name = $('#name').val();

    $.ajax({
     url:'php/page.php',
     data: 'name='+name, //sending the data to page.php
     success: function(data) {  
      $('#content').html(data);

     }
     
    }).error(function() { 
     alert('an error occured');

    }).success(function() { 
     /*alert*/
     alert('an error occured');
    }).complete(function() { 
     /*alert*/
    });
});
```

the `error()` is not working, when I change the URL: to `page.php` with incorrect extension to check for an `error()` and display it.

But, in console it displays an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).error is not a function

Comment: Make sure you have properly included the jQuery library.

Comment: jQuery library might be missing

Comment: add a functional snippet

Answer (score 22):

Since version 3.0, jQuery replaces `error()` with `fail()` for chained promise call. So you should use

```
$.ajax({ 
    .... 
}).done(function(resp){
    //do something when ok
}).fail(function(err) {
    //do something when something is wrong
}).always(function() {
   //do  something whether request is ok or fail
});
```

From [jQuery Ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are using the slim build of jquery which does not have ajax function. Try to download the regular one from this [link](http://jquery.com/%20download/#jquery)

Comment: That was my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things here.

First make sure Ajax is there in your Jquery file using below code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log($.ajax);
    });
  </script>
```

If this prints error, then you don’t have Ajax. In this case, change you jquery to point to CDN like https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js.

Secondly change you Ajax function to below. Here i modified the error and complete function plus removed duplicate success function.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'php/page.php',
    data: 'name='+name, //sending the data to page.php
    success: function(data) {  
        $('#content').html(data);
    }, error : function(e) { 
        alert('an error occured');
    }, complete : function() { 
        /*alert*/
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer but if you could answer me ill be thankful.
i tried this `console.log($.ajax);` it didn't print error, but it prints undefined!

Answer (score 2):

You are using slim version of jQuery. It Doesn't support ajax Calling. Use following cdn

> ```
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
> ```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jquery examples - 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">


</head>
<body>


<input id="name" type="text" name=""> <input id="button" type="button" value="load" name="">


        <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectors12.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```