# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).error is not a function in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make a like button using ajax and found the following error:

***Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).error is not a function***

```
$(function () {
  $(".post-like").on("click", function () {
    var post_id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/post/like/"+post_id,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: 'json'
    }).error(function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    });
  });
});
```

while I already installed the latest jquery by webpacker and gem and imported all of them (the dollar sign works properly).

Comment: what jQuery version you are using? if it's 3 then use `.fail`.[Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(…).error is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974868/uncaught-typeerror-ajax-error-is-not-a-function/53372059)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used jq version 3.5.1. I also got the log data of $.ajax and found that the ajax function is available.

Comment: `$.ajax` is available that's why you are able to use it, but instead of `.error`, now you have to use `.fail`

Comment: Sorry for being stupid sir but I used fail to print out the log and it works but dont know how to move further

Comment: Okay I found it I treid using js in json.erb thank you for helping