# JAVASCRIPT Error exporting div to PDF

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to export a div to pdf when I click the button, however I get a javascript function error that I can not solve, can anyone help me?

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DymjI.png)

**JavaScript**

```
 <script language="javascript">
var cache_width = $('#renderPDF').width(); //Criado um cache do CSS
var a4 = [595.28, 841.89]; // Widht e Height de uma folha a4

    $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
        // Setar o width da div no formato a4
        $("#renderPDF").width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');

        // Aqui ele cria a imagem e cria o pdf
        html2canvas($('#renderPDF'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
                var doc = new jsPDF({ unit: 'px', format: 'a4' });
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
                doc.save('NOME-DO-PDF.pdf');
                //Retorna ao CSS normal
                $('#renderPDF').width(cache_width);
            }
        });
    });            
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive panel" id="renderPDF">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> Cliente ID</td>
        <td>@Model.ID_Cliente</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Nome</td>
        <td>@Model.Nome</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Morada</td>
        <td>@Model.Morada</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`live` method is deprecated and probably removed in your jQuery version.

Try using `on` instead.

Comment: It worked when replacing live by on. However, I get an error saying Uncaught Invalid orientation: [object object]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jquery are you using? .live has been removed from version 1.9 on wards.

```
$(document).on("click", '#btnPrint', function () {
        // Setar o width da div no formato a4
        $("#renderPDF").width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');

        // Aqui ele cria a imagem e cria o pdf
        html2canvas($('#renderPDF'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
                var doc = new jsPDF({ unit: 'px', format: 'a4' });
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
                doc.save('NOME-DO-PDF.pdf');
                //Retorna ao CSS normal
                $('#renderPDF').width(cache_width);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm using these scripts `                        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Since you are using a version newer than 1.9, live won't work. I have updated the code. You will have to use on.

Comment: It worked when replacing live by on. However, I get an error saying Uncaught Invalid orientation: [object object]

Comment: You are not using html2canvas correctly. Read the documentation and see if you can find the error