# Uncaught TypeError: $(.remove).live is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an error in my code:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

That code is for cloning when I click X button it should remove, but it doesn't and when I debug using F12 it gave me the error.

[image]

When I click the remove button the red one it would not remove

```js
$('.remove').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<td><a class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>
```

Comment: Use .on() instead of .live()

Comment: Note that you need to use the *delegated* signature of the `on()` method, eg. `$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API **live()** has been removed in jQuery 1.9; use **on()** instead.

Comment: This answer doesn't add much value over the [duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function). [Try to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) answering questions that already have answers on Stack Overflow.