# Updating CODE on wordpress - use the on() instead live()

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with the theme i use, no longer supported  .

***/wp-content/themes/country-inn/assets/js/page-builder-widgets.js: jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated

The problem is in this line:

jQuery(“.pt-country-inn-remove”).live(‘click’, function() {
jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();

Can anyone please tell me how can i change the code on this line of code to update and use use the on() instead.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated code looks like following:

```
   jQuery(“.pt-country-inn-remove”).on(‘click’, 'body' ,function() {

   jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();

   });
```

See [this Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function) for further info.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. after i upgrade the line as you told me to do i still get the same error advice on this file and i can check on the site that the problem is still there. I'll leave the complete file below to find out if there are any further changes needed. Please, help me.

Comment: @Playdiune Can You provide the exact error message, you are receiving? Also in which line does the error occur?

Comment: The error is the one i mentioned in the first post. I allready did the change you told me to do. The entire file is below. I still Get the same error.

Comment: This is the Message i get from the plugin o installed to help me: jQuery Migrate Helper — Warnings encountered
This page generated the following warnings:
https://digusto.pt/wp-content/themes/country-inn/assets/js/page-builder-widgets.js: jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated

Comment: @Playdiune Use DevTools for debugging purposes please. Use e.g chrome , and  click F12 on your keyboard. Show me the Console Output afterwards...

Comment: Found the problem . It was a browser cache problem. After i clean the browser cache, everything is ok. Thanks a lot for your help. After i used the devtools, i saw the changes i had made didnt load on browser. 

Comment: @Playdiune Perfect, if my answer was the one that solved your problem, do not forget to mark it as the accepted answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the file reported. Pleaqse tell me if there is something more to update.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var at_document = $(document);

    at_document.on('click','.media-image-upload', function(e){

        // Prevents the default action from occuring.
        e.preventDefault();
        var media_image_upload = $(this);
        var media_title = $(this).data('title');
        var media_button = $(this).data('button');
        var media_input_val = $(this).prev();
        var media_image_url_value = $(this).prev().prev().children('img');
        var media_image_url = $(this).siblings('.img-preview-wrap');

        var meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
            title: media_title,
            button: { text:  media_button },
            library: { type: 'image' }
        });
        // Opens the media library frame.
        meta_image_frame.open();
        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){

            // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
            var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
            media_input_val.val(media_attachment.url);
            if( media_image_url_value !== null ){
                media_image_url_value.attr( 'src', media_attachment.url );
                media_image_url.show();
                LATESTVALUE(media_image_upload.closest("p"));
            }
        });
    });

   // Runs when the image button is clicked.
    jQuery('body').on('click','.media-image-remove', function(e){
        $(this).siblings('.img-preview-wrap').hide();
        $(this).prev().prev().val('');
    });
   
    var LATESTVALUE = function (wrapObject) {
        wrapObject.find('[name]').each(function(){
            $(this).trigger('change');
        });
    };  

});


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var count = 0;
    jQuery("body").on('click','.pt-country-inn-add', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
       
      var widget_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

      var ID=  $(this).attr('id');
      var arr11 = ID.split('-');
      var num= arr11[2];
      var additional = $(this).parent().parent().find('.pt-country-inn-additional');
      var add = $(this).parent().parent().find('.pt-country-inn-add');
      count = additional.find('.pt-country-inn-sec').length;
   
      //Json response
      $.ajax({
        type      : "GET",
        url       : ajaxurl,
        data      : {
            action: 'business_way_wp_pages_plucker',
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            var options = '<option disabled>Select pages</option>';

            $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                var option = '<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>';
                options += option;
            });


            additional.append(
                '<div class="pt-country-inn-sec"><div class="sub-option section widget-upload">'+
                '<label for="widget-'+widget_id+'-'+num+'-features-'+count+'">Pages</label>'+
                '<select class="widefat" id="widget-'+widget_id+'-'+num+'-features-'+count+'-page_ids"'+
                'name="widgets['+num+'][features]['+count+'][page_ids]">'+ options + '</select>' +
                '<a class="pt-country-inn-remove delete">Remove Feature</a></div></div>' );

        }   
        });   
      
    });

    jQuery(".pt-country-inn-remove").on('click', 'body', function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

});
```